# Python conditionally initialize subclass from one of two parents

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I am using a module that I don't develop that provides two classes Class2D and Class3D.  These classes construct some object from a set of points based on if the points are 2 dimensional or 3 dimensional. I'm trying to write a class that will inherit from one or the other depending on user input.  **I want something like below**

```
def MyClass(Class2D,Class3D):
    def __init__(self,points):
        if points.dimension==2:
            Class2D.__init__(self,points)
        else:
            Class3D.__init__(self,points)

        #other initialization now that class is determined

    #other methods and attributes of MyClass
```

This code doesn't work because Class2D is getting priority for methods but I'm not sure how to work out an alternative.

Comment: @ekhumoro can you elaborate?

Comment: Can this be modified if I need to do other initialization and add other methods to MyClass?  I think my original question was misleading in that I need to do something after the class is determined and initialized, I edited to reflect this.

Comment: Does the new class have to actually **be** an instance of `Class2D` or `Class3D`? That is, does it need to pass `isinstance` checks (or equivalent)?

Comment: No, but it would be nice to have access to Class2D or Class3D methods directly.

Comment: Use `__new__` as suggested in the accepted answer linked above. If inheritance is not important, you could also use a simple delegate pattern. That is, keep an internal instance of the required class, and then add wrapper methods to access whatever functionality you need to expose as a public api.

Comment: You can write the desired functions in `Class2D` and `Class3D` directly in `MyClass`, and keep a record of `self`'s type like `self._type = Class2D`, and `self._type.some_method(self)`. This can be automated by a decorator or metaclass.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the link, the delegate pattern is what I'm using now but it seemed like a better solution than writing a bunch of wrappers existed.

Comment: @liliscent do you have a link/references for automating this with a metaclass/decorator?

Comment: You can traverse the `__dict__` of the base class, and select the methods you want. Then `setattr` to `MyClass` thus adding class method programmatically. You can use a decorator to decorate the definition of `MyClass`, or a metaclass during the creation of `MyClass`. Maybe general reference to metaclass or decorator is enough.